# Stone edging without the trench. What options do I have?

Tags: lawn, landscaping

I have stone edging but I do not want a trench like edgers do. I just want the lawn cut as close as possible to the edge. What options do I have?
I do not like the trench like cut that the edgers like B&D Edge Hog does
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the lawnmower over the top of it, then. That is, run the mower on the edging and grass at the same time to cut the grass all the way up to the edging stones.

Note that if you have individual stones as shown, the grass will infiltrate the joints over time if you are not mechanically edging, (with a trench you don't like) unless you put some other barrier (edging - long strips of metal or plastic, usually) between your edging stones and the grass area, ideally (for grass control, possibly not for walking on) sticking above the surface 1/4" / 6 mm less than your mowing height - or the grass will climb over the barrier and get into the joints anyway.

You'll have to manually pull any grass that gets into the joints to prevent problems with the stone edging. You can choose to not use any other edging and just do that, if you actually do it.

I guess folks do also turn a string trimmer vertical and use it as an edger, don't know if that's different enough to suit you. Suspect it will still leave the root infiltration problem already mentioned.

Comment: Yeah the trimmer used as you described is what I am using but that sends cut grass in areas where I do not want it